# What is the most efficient way to create Date Object in Java

Tags: java, date

I am creating `Date` object in java.

First way:
 By using Calender

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

Second way:

with Date class

```
Date today1 = new Date();
```

Which one is most effective way here?

Comment: Calendar is basically doing the same thing, but it's using the settings of the object to generate the result ;)

Comment: Creating an instance of `java.util.Date` is extremely cheap (just a wrapper around a long-primitive). But using it in formatting (for example in `SimpleDateFormat`) has some performance impact due to lack of thread-safety, enforced conversion using complex gregorian calendar rules and/or use of synchronization overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8 you should go for LocalDateTime or LocalDate:

```
LocalDateTime timePoint = LocalDateTime.now(
    );     // The current date and time
LocalDate.of(2012, Month.DECEMBER, 12); // from values

LocalDate theDate = timePoint.toLocalDate(); // or
theDate = LocalDate.now(); //
```

Fromt the documentation:

> [For example, the existing classes (such as java.util.Date and
>   SimpleDateFormatter) aren’t thread-safe, leading to potential
>   concurrency issues for users—not something the average developer would
>   expect to deal with when writing date-handling code.
>
> Some of the date and time classes also exhibit quite poor API design.
>   For example, years in java.util.Date start at 1900, months start at 1,
>   and days start at 0—not very intuitive.][1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you have to decide between the two. Take the `new Date()`. As the `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` would create a `Calendar` instance which you could not use afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too!
        Date newDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();

Within your options, I will prefer the first alternative.

Comment: Why are you prefer this?. Is there any thing specific to use this?

Comment: but how do you figure out what the year, month, day is?

Comment: I want to create today's date.. how can i use your code?